# Does every table need a primary key?

Tags: key, ms-access-2010, entity-relationship

Take the Loan table below as an example. Does it require any primary key?

[Loan Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWwIx.png)

Comment: How do you intend yto use it? Why do you ask?

Comment: In case for "emergency" you have a better access to each single record.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Your Loan table looks like a junction table, so the PK should be the combination of `DocumentID` and `EmployeeID`.

Comment: I think a document can be borrowed multiple times by the same employee, so it's not unique. If the date fields are `datetime` you can add one to get it unique, but I would advise to use an`id`field that auto increments in every table as primary key to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Does every table NEED a primary key: No.

SHOULD every table have a primary key: Yes. There may be situations where a table doesn't need a primary key, but those are rare and in general every table should have one. This is because you will want to uniquely identify a record and it becomes difficult to work with records that don't have primary keys.

In your case, YES your loan table should have a primary key. As Andre has already said in his answer it should be a combination of the `DocumentID` and the `EmployeeID`.

At the risk of introducing some confusion: Use either `DocumentID` + `EmployeeID` or `EmployeeID` + `DocumentID`. The order can make a difference. If you go for say `DocumentID` + `EmployeeID` (in that order) then the database will use the primary key when searching on `DocumentID` plus `EmployeeID` (any order in your query), and for searches on just the `DocumentID` but won't use it when searching on just `EmployeeID`.